# Next.js Express Custom Server { dev: true } loads forever (empty response) but production { dev: false } works

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I am using a express custom server with next.js. [Custom Server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server)

I added the next app to my router under the path `/custom/uibackend/next`

```js
const next = require('next')
const app = next({ dev: true, dir: './', conf: { } })

const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

module.exports = router => {
  router.all('*', (req, res) => handle(req, res))
}
```

If i run my app and access the route in the browser it loads for a while and gives a empty response back. 
There is just this one log i the console: 
`info  - Using webpack 5. Reason: Enabled by default https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5`

If i build the app and set dev to false it works as expected and i can access the route and the pages.

```js
const app = next({ dev: false, dir: './', conf: { } })
```

I used the following next.config.js file:

```js
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/custom/uibackend/next'
}
```

My /pages folder is in the root.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the error.

I forgot to call `app.prepare()`

```js
app.prepare().then(() => {

// add handle to router/app after app.prepare has finished

})
```